# how to pass a NSString from NSObject to UIViewcontrller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand this is a very basic question, but as a beginner who already google a bunch of resources I just couldn't make it. I would like to pass a `NSString` from a `NSObject` to `UIViewController`. I know if want to pass a value to another class I need to make it public. I have a method in DataConnection.m

```
- (void)jsonParse{

    NSString* path  = @"http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    NSDictionary* resultDic = [dic objectForKey:@"maxid"];
    NSString* recData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"recommendData"];
    NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
    NSString* lData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];

    NSLog(@"recommendData = %@, room = %@, level = %@",recData,rData,lData);
    self->_room = rData;
    self->_level = lData;
    self->_recommendID = recData;

}
```

what I want to do is to pass the value of recData to another `UIViewController`. So I have made a code in 'h:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *recommendID;
```

in my UIViewController I have this code:

```
[self.delegate NextScreen: self ndx: recData];
```

I would like pass value to reData. Anyone tell me how to do that?? sorry for my programme knowledge!

~~~ update~~~
I have put the codes like this:

```
DataConnection *data = [[DataConnection alloc] init];
[data jsonParse];
[self.delegate NextScreen: self ndx: [data.recommendID]];
```

but i got expected identifier??

Comment: you want to move a string from one view controller to another controller

Comment: `dateCon = [[DateConectio alloc] init]; [dateCon jsonParse];` and access your property via dateCon variable in viewController.

Comment: no~~~recData is a value from database, and the method is in a NSObject not a view controller

Comment: I got error of use undeclared identifier"dateCon"??

Comment: To let an instance `A` to interact with another instance `B` you need to have a reference  `* B` available at the instance of `A`, then you can use public variables, properties and methods of `B` from `A`.

Comment: mmmmmm~i have try some code like
DataConnection *data = [DataConnection jsonParse]; 

but i got error of no known class method for selector of "jsonParse" 
ps: i have put - (void)jsonParse; in DataConnection.h

Comment: Note the 'alloc' and 'init' parts of the sample you were given.  Take a look at the difference between class methods and instance methods in some Objective-C documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> "mmmmmm~i have try some code like DataConnection *data =
>   [DataConnection jsonParse]; but i got error of no known class method
>   for selector of "jsonParse" ps: i have put 
>    - (void)jsonParse; in DataConnection.h –"

Above mentioned way is wrong way of calling a method. you can call it this way:

`DataConnection *data = [[DataConnection alloc] init];
[data jsonParse];`

But, as per your question,

> "what I want to do is to pass the value of recData to another
>   UIViewController. So I have made a code in 'h:"

Change the return type of jsonParse to NSDictionary and return the resultDic which you wish to transfer.

```
- (NSDictionary *)jsonParse{

    NSString* path  = @"http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    NSDictionary* resultDic = [dic objectForKey:@"maxid"];
   /* NSString* recData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"recommendData"];
    NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
    NSString* lData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];

    NSLog(@"recommendData = %@, room = %@, level = %@",recData,rData,lData);
    self->_room = rData;
    self->_level = lData;
    self->_recommendID = recData;*/

    return resultDic;
}
```

In your view controller,

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *resultDict;
@synthesize resultDict;

DataConnection *data = [[DataConnection alloc] init];
 self.resultDict = (NSDictionary *)[data jsonParse];
 _recommendID = [resultDic objectForKey:@"recommendData"];
 _room = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
 _level = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];
```

now recommendID will have the recData value.

Comment: i have put the codes like this, DataConnection *data = [[DataConnection alloc] init];
    [data jsonParse];
    [self.delegate NextScreen: self ndx: [data.recommendID]];

Comment: but i need rData and lData for uialertview! can I just obtain value from recData???

Comment: I have edited my answer. check it... return dictionary in jsonParse and extract necessary values in view controller.

Comment: maybe, I did not describe properly. The value of rData and lData will be used in dataconnection. it means that these two values should stay in that class. The viewcontroller will only take recData. sorry for the misunderstanding!!

Comment: you can use them with these lines....
    NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
    NSString* lData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];
....and return what you need in viewcontroller..

Answer (score 0):

have you included

```
 @synthesize recommendID;
```

in the DataConnection.m file?

I did consider adding this as a comment, but i dont have enough reputation for commenting.